# Node.js, Express and Postgres design

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am creating an API with Node.js and Express. I'm using Postgres as DB.

I would like to create a "global object", called DBConn or something, that I can access from everywhere in the App. This object would have the functions for inserting, updating, validating, etc.

How would be the general architecture in Node and Express for this to work? Does it make sense in Node to instantiate it just once and keep the communication with the DB open, or should I instantiate it everytime I want to perform a DB action?

Answer (score 2):

Here's everything that you are looking for, using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise):

```
// Users repository:
var repUsers = function (obj) {
    return {
        add: function (name) {
            return obj.none("insert into users(name) values($1)", name);
        },
        delete: function (id) {
            return obj.none("delete from users where id=$1", id);
        }
        // etc...
    };
};

var options = {
    extend: function () {
        // extending the protocol:
        this.users = repUsers(this);
    }
};

var pgp = require('pg-promise')(options);

var cn = "postgres://username:password@host:port/database";

var db = pgp(cn); // your global database instance;

db.users.add("John")
    .then(function () {
        // success;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // error;
    });
```

This will also manage your database connection automatically, you will just keep using variable `db` throughout your application.

And setting up a repository is optional, you can always use in-line queries instead. See [the library](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) for details and [more examples](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example).

Comment: But that will just work within the same *.js file, right? I'm using Express, and I've several files under the /routes folder, there is actually where I'm going to perform most of the db stuff. Should I copypaste this code (or import it) to each js file, or by setting it in the main app.js is ok?

Comment: @CarlosNavarro of course not! :) You need to get familiar with the concept of NodeJS modules, how to use `module.exports`. It is really simple, and is the very ABC for writing applications with NodeJS.

Comment: I see! So if I save this on a separate js file and rename the var "db" to "exports.db", will that be enough? Or I should add the "exports.*" to every variable? After all the only var I will be using "globally" is just "db", am I right?

Comment: Something like this :) Functionality of NodeJS modules isn't really something to be discussed here. It's an entirely different topic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Postgres at all,but maybe you can try this:

Create a file named 'DBConn.js' in YourApp/common directory.

DBConn.js:

```
var DBConn = exports = modules.exports = {}

//code to connect to database
....

//insert update detele select
DBConn.insert = function(arguments) {
    //some code 
}

.....

DBConn.update = function(arguments) {
    //some code 
}
```

Then you can require it in any other controller like YouApp/controller/UserController.js

UserController.js:

```
var DBConn = require('../common/DBConn.js')
```

---

Example of module cache

index.js:

```
require('./DB.js');
require('./DB.js');
```

DB.js

```
var DB = exports = module.exports = {}

function connect() {
    //connect to database code
    console.log('Connect!');
}

connect();


//other code
```

Then `node index.js`,we can see that 'Connect!' only logged once.
Because when we first require('DB.js'),node.js put it to the module cache,and when we require DB.js again,we get DB.js from cache.

Comment: Thanks! Now I want to take it a little further. The thing is: I have the "main app" (app.js) where I set the "var DBConn = require...". But then the routes are handled by some other js files (that are also required from app.js). I want to have access from those other js files to the DBConn of the app.js. Of course I could require it from those js files but then the connection to the DB would be re-established.

Comment: Thanks for node.js module cache,you don't need to worry about this!I will give you a example in my answer.